# cannot import name 'InvalidAlgorithmError' from 'jwt'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am trying to implement djangorestframework-simplejwt in **djanog project**.
when I try to post username and password show error.

include this following line.

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

```
asgiref==3.5.2
Django==4.0
djangorestframework==3.14.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.2.2
mysqlclient==2.1.1
PyJWT==2.6.0
pytz==2022.6
sqlparse==0.4.3
tzdata==2022.6
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

By any chance your project or any application inside your project is named 'jwt' like below?

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'jwt',
]
```

I had a the same error when I named an app inside the project 'jwt'. Changing the name of the app should resolve the issue.

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'jwt_auth',
]
```

Answer (score -1):

change the name of your project , make sure project name is not same as 'jwt'.